# Export Data's from dataGrid in to excel

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, export-to-excel

how can I export data's from a datagrid in to excel.I'm new at flex.I've no idea about it. Can any one help me for doing this or suggest any examples?pls help me...

Comment: Search for as3xls-1.0.swc, By using this swc you can do it on client side. you can find n number of examples....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see a below tutorial:

[Import/Export data in/out of a Datagrid in Flex](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Import_Export_data_in_out_of_a_Datagrid_in_Flex-17223.html)

[DataGrid data Export to Excel](http://www.justskins.com/forums/datagrid-data-export-to-43645.html)

Comment: I created a datagrid and also created some text box and a submit button outside the datagrid.. if we entered some data's into the text box and then click the submit button the data's are stored into the datagrid.. i want to export these data from the data grid is export into excel.How it  possiple?How can i create a excel sheet and how it connect with my datagrid?

Comment: @Dipin - As you have explained that data is inside dataGrid make sure that dataProvider is updated (dataProvider of dataGrid). If dataProvider is update as3xls-1.0.swc will take care of exporting it....to xls