# Export datagrid to excel

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, export-to-excel

I created a datagrid and also created some text box and a submit button outside the datagrid.. if we entered some data's into the text box and then click the submit button the data's are stored into the datagrid.. i want to export these data from the data grid is export into excel.How it possiple?How can i create a excel sheet and how it connect with my datagrid?
My code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.effects.easing.Exponential;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            [Bindable]
            public var dgItems_client:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            public var dgItems_admin:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            public var temp_client:Object = new Object();
            public var temp_admin:Object = new Object();
            private var fileRef:FileReference=new FileReference;
            private var sheet:Sheet;
            //          public var imagegrid:Image;
            private function tabChange():void
            {
                errorAdmin.visible=false;
                errorClient.visible=false;
                if(gh.selectedChild.name=='clientTab')
                {
                    details.dataProvider=dgItems_client;
                    arrayName.headerText="Client_Name";
                }
                else
                {
                    details.dataProvider=dgItems_admin;
                    arrayName.headerText="Admin_Name";
                }
            }
            private function submitClick():void
            {
                if(name_client.text!="" && address_client.text!="" && phone_client.text!="")
                {

                    temp_client = ({Name:name_client.text, Address:address_client.text,Phone_Number:phone_client.text});
                    dgItems_client.addItem(temp_client);
                    name_client.text="";
                    address_client.text="";
                    phone_client.text="";
                    clientClick();
                    errorClient.visible=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorClient.visible=true;
                }
                if(name_admin.text!=""&&address_admin.text!=""&&phone_admin.text!="")
                {
                    temp_admin = ({Name:name_admin.text, Address:address_admin.text,Phone_Number:phone_admin.text});
                    dgItems_admin.addItem(temp_admin);
                    name_admin.text="";
                    address_admin.text="";
                    phone_admin.text="";
                    errorAdmin.visible=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorAdmin.visible=true;
                }

            }
            private function clientClick():void
            {

                details.dataProvider=dgItems_client;
                arrayName.headerText="Client_Name";
            }
            private function adminClick():void
            {

                details.dataProvider=dgItems_admin;
                arrayName.headerText="Admin_Name";
            }
            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,fileSelected);

            }
            private function fileSelected():void
            {

            }
            private function executeExport():void
            {
                 sheet=new Sheet;
//               var dataProviderCollection:ArrayCollection;
                var rowCount:int=details.columnsLength;
                Alert.show(rowCount.toString());
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:TabNavigator x="27" y="11" width="455" height="376" id="gh" change="tabChange()" backgroundColor="#A4B6E9">
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Client" id="clientTab">
            <s:Label x="10" y="30" width="52" height="25" text="Name:"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="127" width="52" height="28" text="Address:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="name_client" x="69" y="18" width="188" height="37" restrict="a-zA-Z"/>
            <s:TextArea id="address_client" x="70" y="70" height="126"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="230" width="84" height="32" text="Phone:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="phone_client" x="70" y="218" width="188" height="30" restrict="0-9" maxChars="10"/>
            <s:Button x="100" y="291" height="28" label="Submit"  click="submitClick()"/>           
            <s:Label id="errorClient" x="59" y="270" width="171" height="27" text="please fill the blank fields" color="red" visible="false"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Admin" id="adminTab" >
            <s:Label x="23" y="48" width="52" height="25" text="Name:"/>
            <s:Label x="26" y="148" width="52" height="28" text="Address:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="name_admin" x="105" y="33" width="188" height="37"/>
            <s:TextArea id="address_admin" x="105" y="93" height="126"/>
            <s:Label x="26" y="257" width="84" height="32" text="Phone:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="phone_admin" x="104" y="246" width="188" height="30" restrict="0-9" maxChars="10"/>
            <s:Button x="137" y="305" height="28" label="Submit" click="submitClick()"/>
            <s:Label id="errorAdmin" x="100" y="286" width="171" height="17" color="red" fontSize="14"
                     text="please fill the blank fields" visible="false"/>
            <s:Button x="335" y="60" height="34" label="Admin Details" click="adminClick()"/>
            <s:Button x="335" y="180" height="34" label="Client Details" click="clientClick()"/>

        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
    <s:TitleWindow x="521" y="84" width="377" height="234">
        <s:DataGrid x="0" y="0" width="375" height="163" borderVisible="true" id="details">
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Name" id="arrayName"></s:GridColumn>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Address" headerText="Address"></s:GridColumn>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Phone_Number" headerText="Phone_Number"></s:GridColumn>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
        <s:Button x="139" y="167" height="28" label="Export" click="executeExport()"/>
    </s:TitleWindow>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070347/export-datas-from-datagrid-in-to-excel. Suggestion: - You should try to modify your original post not to create new one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok...
You can try below code: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
               >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.effects.easing.Exponential;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            [Bindable]
            public var dgItems_client:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            public var dgItems_admin:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            public var temp_client:Object = new Object();
            public var temp_admin:Object = new Object();

            private function tabChange():void
            {
                errorAdmin.visible=false;
                errorClient.visible=false;
                if(gh.selectedChild.name=='clientTab')
                {
                    details.dataProvider=dgItems_client;
                    arrayName.headerText="Client_Name";
                }
                else
                {
                    details.dataProvider=dgItems_admin;
                    arrayName.headerText="Admin_Name";
                }
            }
            private function submitClick():void
            {
                if(gh.selectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    if(name_client.text!="" && address_client.text!="" && phone_client.text!="")
                    {

                        temp_client = ({Name:name_client.text, Address:address_client.text,Phone_Number:phone_client.text});
                        dgItems_client.addItem(temp_client);
                        name_client.text="";
                        address_client.text="";
                        phone_client.text="";
                        clientClick();
                        errorClient.visible=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorClient.visible=true;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    if(name_admin.text!="" && address_admin.text!="" && phone_admin.text!="")
                    {
                        temp_admin = ({Name:name_admin.text, Address:address_admin.text,Phone_Number:phone_admin.text});
                        dgItems_admin.addItem(temp_admin);
                        name_admin.text="";
                        address_admin.text="";
                        phone_admin.text="";
                        errorAdmin.visible=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorAdmin.visible=true;
                    }
                }
            }

            private function clientClick():void
            {

                details.dataProvider=dgItems_client;
                arrayName.headerText="Client_Name";
            }
            private function adminClick():void
            {

                details.dataProvider=dgItems_admin;
                arrayName.headerText="Admin_Name";
            }

            private function executeExport():void
            {
                ExcelExporterUtil.dataGridExporter(this.details, "prueba_excel.xls");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:TabNavigator x="27" y="11" width="455" height="376" id="gh" change="tabChange()" backgroundColor="#A4B6E9">
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Client" id="clientTab">
            <s:Label x="10" y="30" width="52" height="25" text="Name:"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="127" width="52" height="28" text="Address:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="name_client" x="69" y="18" width="188" height="37" restrict="a-zA-Z"/>
            <s:TextArea id="address_client" x="70" y="70" height="126"/>
            <s:Label x="10" y="230" width="84" height="32" text="Phone:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="phone_client" x="70" y="218" width="188" height="30" restrict="0-9" maxChars="10"/>
            <s:Button x="100" y="291" height="28" label="Submit"  click="submitClick()"/>           
            <s:Label id="errorClient" x="59" y="270" width="171" height="27" text="please fill the blank fields" color="red" visible="false"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Admin" id="adminTab" >
            <s:Label x="23" y="48" width="52" height="25" text="Name:"/>
            <s:Label x="26" y="148" width="52" height="28" text="Address:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="name_admin" x="105" y="33" width="188" height="37"/>
            <s:TextArea id="address_admin" x="105" y="93" height="126"/>
            <s:Label x="26" y="257" width="84" height="32" text="Phone:"/>
            <s:TextInput id="phone_admin" x="104" y="246" width="188" height="30" restrict="0-9" maxChars="10"/>
            <s:Button x="137" y="305" height="28" label="Submit" click="submitClick()"/>
            <s:Label id="errorAdmin" x="100" y="286" width="171" height="17" color="red" fontSize="14"
                     text="please fill the blank fields" visible="false"/>
            <s:Button x="335" y="60" height="34" label="Admin Details" click="adminClick()"/>
            <s:Button x="335" y="180" height="34" label="Client Details" click="clientClick()"/>

        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
    <s:TitleWindow x="521" y="84" width="377" height="234">
        <mx:DataGrid x="0" y="0" width="375" height="163" borderVisible="true" id="details">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Name" id="arrayName"></mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Address" headerText="Address"></mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Phone_Number" headerText="Phone_Number"></mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <s:Button x="139" y="167" height="28" label="Export" click="executeExport()"/>
    </s:TitleWindow>
</s:Application>
```

**ExcelExporterUtil.as**

```
package 
{
    import com.as3xls.xls.ExcelFile;
    import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;

    import flash.errors.IllegalOperationError;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.ICollectionView;
    import mx.collections.IViewCursor;
    import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
    import mx.controls.DataGrid;

    public class ExcelExporterUtil
    {
        public function ExcelExporterUtil()
        {
            throw new IllegalOperationError("Class \"ExcelExporterUtil\" is static. You can't instance this");
        }

        static public function dataGridExporter(dg:DataGrid, defaultName:String):void
        {
            if (dg == null || dg.dataProvider == null || defaultName == null || defaultName == "")
                return;

            var cols:Number = 0;
            var colsValues:Array = [];
            var cantCols:Number = dg.columnCount;
            var fieldT:String;
            var headerT:String;

            // armo el listado de headers y variables para cada columna
            for ( ; cols < cantCols; cols++)
            {
                headerT = (dg.columns[cols] as Object).headerText
                fieldT = (dg.columns[cols] as Object).dataField;
                if ( fieldT == null || fieldT == "" || headerT == null || headerT == "")
                    continue; 
                colsValues.push({
                    header:headerT,
                    value:fieldT
                });
            }

            if ( colsValues.length == 0 )
                return;

            ExcelExporterUtil.export(dg.dataProvider, colsValues, defaultName);
        }

        static public function chartExporter(chart:ByteArray, defautlName:String):void
        {
            if(chart)
            {
                var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();
                sheet.resize(1, 1);
                sheet.setCell(0, 0, "Chart Data");

                sheet.setCell(0,0,chart);

                var xls:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
                xls.sheets.addItem(sheet);
                var bytes:ByteArray = xls.saveToByteArray();

                var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
                fr.save(bytes, defautlName);    
            }
        }

        static public function export(obj:Object, colsValues:Array, defautlName:String):void
        {
            var _dp:ICollectionView = ExcelExporterUtil.getDataProviderCollection(obj);
            if ( _dp == null )
                return;

            var rows:Number = 0;
            var cols:Number = 0;
            var cantCols:Number = colsValues.length;
            var sheet:Sheet = new Sheet();
            sheet.resize(_dp.length, colsValues.length);

            for ( ; cols < cantCols; cols++)
            {
                sheet.setCell(rows, cols, colsValues[cols].header);
            }

            cols = 0;
            rows++;
            var cursor:IViewCursor = _dp.createCursor();
            while ( !cursor.afterLast )
            {
                for (cols = 0 ; cols < cantCols; cols++)
                {
                    if ( (cursor.current as Object).hasOwnProperty(colsValues[cols].value) )
                        sheet.setCell(rows, cols, (cursor.current as Object));
                }

                rows++;
                cursor.moveNext();
            }

            var xls:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
            xls.sheets.addItem(sheet);
            var bytes:ByteArray = xls.saveToByteArray();

            var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fr.save(bytes, defautlName);
        }

        static private function getDataProviderCollection(obj:Object):ICollectionView
        {
            if ( (obj is Number && isNaN(obj as Number)) || (!(obj is Number) && obj == null))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if ( obj is ICollectionView )
            {
                return obj as ICollectionView;
            }
            else if ( obj is Array )
            {
                return new ArrayCollection(obj as Array);
            }
            else if ( obj is XMLList )
            {
                return new XMLListCollection(obj as XMLList);
            }
            else if ( obj is XML )
            {
                var col:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
                col.addItem(obj);
                return col;
            }
            else if ( obj is Object )
            {
                return new ArrayCollection([obj]);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope may help you....
Note: - i am using ExcelExporterUtil.as from one of the post.. not created by me..

Or Other way, can refer below post: -
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Import_Export_data_in_out_of_a_Datagrid_in_Flex-17223.html

Comment: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Import_Export_data_in_out_of_a_Datagrid_in_Flex-17223.html   this link help me for completing this task

Comment: Just a comment: If you have formatting in the grid (thru label functions), it will get lost as the code doesnt consider that.